# Class 'cakeEmail' not found - cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got this eror while trying to send email with cakeMail. Although I have following code from the cookbook 1 on 1.
Here are some snippets from my controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
...
...
...
public function index() {
            ....
    $Email = new cakeEmail('smtp');
    $Email->template('MassMail')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->viewVars([
        'content' => $content
    ])
    ->from(['info@forkom-jerman.org' => 'Forkom Jerman'])
    ->to($to)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->replyTo('forkom.jerman@gmail.com')
    ->transport('smtp');
    if ($Email->send()) {
        $this->Flash->set('Email Telah terkirim');
    } else {
        $this->Flash->set('Email tidak bisa terkirim');
    }   
}
```

On the email.php on config folder:

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => 'info@forkom-jerman.org',
        'host' => 'send.one.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => '*****@gmail.com',
        'password' => '******',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
}
```

Please tell me where it went wrong.

Comment: Did you try this way: `$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class to use is **C**akeEmail instead of cakeEmail.
You need to instantiate it like this:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
```

Comment: you are right,
i'm to stupid to figure that one out myself -_-
Thanks!